Failing to Identify the best way to set a Moving Average Threshold to use in my MQL5 EA
Iam writing code in MQl5 for an EA that uses Moving Average. I have a part where I get the Moving Average value at that point and compare it with a value which is the moving average threshold after which I base on that to proceed with other logic. My problem is I need a standard way to determine this moving average threshold. I have read but most just say pick a value near the current price but that hasn't yielded much because how near is not defined. Please help me on this.
Below is the code I use to compare Moving Average with Threshold
     {
      Print("MA is below the threshold. Waiting...");
      return; // Exit if MA is below threshold
     }```


I have two ways :

Using the "strategy tester" and updating your "Expert Advisor" parameters with each test at different time intervals (for example daily, weekly, ...)

If you have a suitable server for this purpose, you can write a piece of code for this purpose and put it in the "timer" event so that the parameters are automatically updated. (update parameters in shorter time)


